# Cannot edit Excel Menus using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create my own menu in Excel's (2010) Ribbon.

I wrote the following Sub to create a 'test' menu but I cannot find any evidence that the menu was created other than it being listed in the `Controls` Collection.

I feel like I've done everything correctly especially since I looked up bunch of code samples ([example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508923.aspx), this does not work for me either) from other people as well.

I guess my question is twofold, does the code below produce a new menu in **YOUR** Excel, and if so any idea why would this fail on my computer?

```
Sub CreateInterface()
  Dim Controls As CommandBarControls
  Dim CmdBar As CommandBarControl
  Dim NewMenu As CommandBarControl

  Set Controls = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls

  Set NewMenu = Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Temporary:=True, before:=Controls.Count)
  NewMenu.Caption = "&Test"
  NewMenu.Visible = True
  For Each CmdBar In Controls
      Debug.Print CmdBar.Caption & "|" & CmdBar.Tag
  Next
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Thanks to D.O. I can see that the code is working it just isn't creating a new menu in the ribbon (like the default ones (Home, Insert, Page Layout, etc.)).

That being said to the best of my knowledge this was supposed to create a new menu, not an item in one of the menus, how can I actually create a new menu?

Comment: It worked for me. I have Excel 2010.

Comment: In that case this must be related to an Excel setting outside of my code.

Comment: @D.O. thanks for checking

Comment: Can you see "Add-on" menu? I have "Test" menu in it.

Comment: omg yes! but that means that my code is not doing what I want it to.

Comment: I have to admit it did bug that Microsoft was telling me to use`msoControlPopup` as a type of my control, but I just took it for granted that this is a menu not a popup.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the old (pre-2007) CommandBars and Controls way is obsolete enough that it only adds buttons to the "Add-ins" ribbon tab.  This is for backward compatibility with old Office solutions, so that they can still be used (somewhat) under 2007+ Office apps.

The way forward (if you plan on using Office 2007 and up) is to modify the ribbon itself.  It's a completely new paradigm, and real-time customizations are done in a completely different way, but if you get the hang of it (it's not that difficult) it is quite useful.I suggest Googling some ribbon tutorials, and using the "Custom UI editor" tool to add your ribbon code to your Office files.  [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)'s web site is always a good resource for more information.